# Unique issue with WooCommerce and hiding the add to cart button..?

Tags: woocommerce

We have [a plugin that allows people to submit offers on products](https://wordpress.org/plugins/offers-for-woocommerce/), and then the site owner can accept, counter, or decline offers, and you can negotiate back and forth until a price agreement is reached.

We are using the `woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button` hook to add the offer button after the cart button.

We are getting lots of feedback that people want to leave the price of the product empty so that it simply display a price on the site, it won't display the Add to Cart button, but they do want it to display the offer button and allow that functionality.

If you set the price to 0.00, then it says FREE on the site, and still includes the add to cart button, so that's no good.

When left blank, though, the problem we run into is that when a customer clicks to buy a product from an accepted offer, WooCommerce keeps removing the item out of the cart because it says it's not purchase.  This is happening because of the [is_purchasable() function](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php#L792-L810).  With a blank price WC says the product is not purchasable, so it will automatically remove itself out of the cart, which it is indeed doing.

There is a hook available that allows us to force `$purchasable = true` for the product, but then of course that makes the Add to Cart button show up again, which doesn't make sense for this use-case.

So as it stands now we're at that point.  We've got the system overriding $purchasable so that we can complete the checkout on a product with an empty price, but it's leaving the Add to Cart button, which allows the person to add the product at 0.00.

I'm stumped on the best way to hide to the Add to Cart button in this scenario..??  I would usually hide it by using that hook to make $purchasable = false, which takes care of it nicely, but in this case I can't do that because that's what keeps us from being able to purchase the product, of course.

Any information on a way around this would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

I found this tutorial for overriding core template files from a plugin:  https://www.skyverge.com/blog/override-woocommerce-template-file-within-a-plugin/

So I think what we're going to try is to basically say "if $purchasable = false and $offers_enabled = true, then use these templates for the add to cart button."

Within our template we're doing nothing but commenting out the actual `<button>` element.  This leaves all hooks in place, but hides our button.

Decent solution?  Horrible idea?

Comment: Couldn't you just use add a css class with `display: none;` on the price element and then using php add the class before an offer has been made and remove it after the first offer? Or something similar anyway.

Comment: So you're going a little different direction then..??  Instead of leaving the price empty, you're saying to go ahead and set a price, but then hide the price element for that product instead of trying to mess with hiding the add to cart button..??

Comment: Essentially yes. It's slightly dodgy. But only slightly.

Comment: Yeah, and it throws some of the other things for a loop, too.  When site owners are managing offers, they like to look at the original price while comparing to offers.  If the original price on these is filled in with random values it's going to confuse them.  They want to be able to easily see from the offer admin that the original price was empty in these cases.